# How to search for broken links on the entire local file system of a server?

Tags: filesystems, symbolic-link, ksh

I have to do this in korn because bash is not installed.  This is my script so far but it's not quite working as I expect.

```
cd /
find . -xdev -type d > /tmp/dirlist
export YOURLIST=`cat /tmp/dirlist2`
echo START > /tmp/final
for a in $YOURLIST; do
   export MYLIST=`ll $a | grep "\->" | awk '{print $11;}'`
   echo in dir $a >> /tmp/final
   sleep 5
   for b in $MYLIST; do
      echo `ll $b` 2>&1 > /tmp/result
      grep -q not /tmp/result
      export RC=$?
      if [ "$RC" = "0" ]
      then
         cat /tmp/result >> /tmp/final
      fi
   done
done
```

Currently it is only printing directories to `/tmp/final` and it's still displaying *not found* messages to `stdout` strangely enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a two fold thing to simulate what was missing in glenn's response

```
root@system:/ $ cat /bin/checklink
export ORIGINAL=`ll $1 | awk '{print $9;}'`
export ORIGINALDIR=`dirname $ORIGINAL`
export LINKIS=`ll $1 | awk '{print $11;}'`
export FOUND="0"
if [ -d ${ORIGINALDIR}/${LINKIS} ]
then
     export FOUND="1"
else if [ -f ${ORIGINALDIR}/${LINKIS} ]
     then
       export FOUND="2"
     else if [ -d ${LINKIS} ]
        then
           export FOUND="3"
        else if [ -f ${LINKIS} ]
             then
                export FOUND="4"
             fi
        fi
     fi
fi
if [ "$FOUND" = "0" ]
then
   echo $1 pointing to $LINKIS not found
fi
```

Followed by a call to

```
`find / -xdev -type l -exec checklink {} \;
```

Feel free to improve...

Answer (score 1):

`find` should be able to find symlinks, you don't have to fall back on [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

```
find / -xdev -type l -print |
while IFS= read -r f; do
    target=$(readlink "$f")
    [[ -e "$target" ]] || echo "broken symlink: $f -> $target"
done
```

Comment: readlink not found... but i get the gist of it

Comment: what's your OS?

Comment: Nearly everyone ever made including NCR.